# Can't see bootstrap modal in design view

Tags: c#, twitter-bootstrap, visual-studio-2012, modal-dialog

so I wanted to add a bootstrap modal to my webpage in order to use it for registration. It would only appear when the "create button" is clicked. It works fine when run, but I can see it at all in the design view of VS
Here is its code, it was put at the end of the body section:

```
 <div class="modal fade" id="register" role="dialog" stle=margin-bottom:60px; margin-top:10px;  >
    <div class="modal-dialog" >
        <div class="modal-content" style="background-color:#fef3df">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h2><strong>Création de Compte</strong></h2>

            </div>

            <div class="modal-body">
                <fieldset>
                <strong>First Name:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <br />
                <br />
                Last Name:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <br />
                <br />
                Email:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox5" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <br />
                <br />

                Department:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <asp:DropDownList ID="DepartmentDropDown" runat="server" style="height:27px; width:190px">
                    <asp:ListItem>Land Assets Department</asp:ListItem>
                     <asp:ListItem>Finance Department</asp:ListItem>


                </asp:DropDownList>
                <br/>
                <br/>
                Username:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox6" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <br />
                <br />
                Password:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox7" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <br />
                <br />
                <br />
                </strong>
               </fieldset>

            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">
                <asp:Button ID="ModalConfirm" style="border-radius:5px;" CssClass="btn-default" runat="server" Text="Fermer" Height="38px"  OnClick="ModalConfirm_Click"   />
                &nbsp;&nbsp;
                <asp:Button ID="Button3" style="border-radius:5px;" CssClass="btn-info" data-dismiss="modal" runat="server" Text="Confirmer" Height="38px" />

            </div>
        </div>

       </div>

   </div>
```

I used the "modal fade" class to hide the modal in the webpage until a button is clicked. However, in visual studio, in the design view, the modal don't appear anymore. I can only access when I run the program, but I can no longer see it in the design view to make some changes to it.

Does anyone know please how to fix that?

Comment: Is this code an accurate copy of what you're using?  The first tag is not correct.  You have a `stle=margin-bottom:60px; margin-top:10px; ` attribute in there that will probably confuse the code editor.

Comment: I removed that style tag on purpose because it was causing a bug, I had no idea why.. But I used it only to change the positioning of the modal, so it has nothing to do with it I think

Answer (score 0):

When you use "modal" class, you are designating the block to be hidden, with the intent to display it later.  That's probably why it's not appearing in the editor: it's supposed to be hidden when the page is viewed.  If you want to view it temporarily in order to preview it, why not just remove those classes and then put them back when you're done?

Comment: You mean I should removed this part: class="modal fade" ?

Comment: Yes.  Just long enough to preview your changes when editing.  Then add them back once you are satisfied with the appearance.